# What's the use of action attribute? - React recaptcha v3

Tags: reactjs, recaptcha-v3

I'm using **react-recaptcha-v3** package for one of the project. In its [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-recaptcha-v3), `ReCaptcha` component uses `action` attribute, and also has [link to google docs](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/v3#actions) for actions. But, I still didn't understand how to use this attribute.

**Is there any simple example showing how to use action *attr*?** Thanks in advance!

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { ReCaptcha } from 'react-recaptcha-v3'

class ExampleComponent extends Component {

  verifyCallback = (recaptchaToken) => {
    // Here you will get the final recaptchaToken!!!  
    console.log(recaptchaToken, "<= your recaptcha token")
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>

        <ReCaptcha
            sitekey="your_site_key"
            action='action_name'
            verifyCallback={this.verifyCallback}
        />

        <h2>Google ReCaptcha with React </h2>

        <code>
          1. Add <strong>your site key</strong> in the ReCaptcha component. <br/>
          2. Check <strong>console</strong> to see the token.
        </code>
      </div>
    );
  };
};

export default ExampleComponent;
```

Comment: Have you been answered elsewhere @Dhruvil21_03 ? I'm also clueless about this prop... Thanks in advance.